# Valores estranhos na saída ao executar aplicação recém compilada

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Quando eu compilo e executo esse código no *Linux*, ele mostra um resultado estranho. Creio que seja lixo da memória. O que está acontecendo para ele mostrar esse resultado, e como posso resolver?

#### Linhas de comando para compilar código

```
gcc -c aluno.c
gcc -c test.c
gcc test.o aluno.o -o test.bin
```

#### Resultado

[image: screenshot com valores estranhos e caractere especial]

#### Arquivo aluno.h

```
/* TAD: Aluno (matricula, nome, curso) */
typedef struct aluno Aluno;

/* Aloca e retorna um aluno com os dados passados por parâmetro */
Aluno *novo(int matricula, char *nome, char *curso);

/* Libera a memória de um aluno previamente criado */
void libera(Aluno *aluno);

/* Copia os valores de um aluno para as referências informadas */
void acessa(Aluno *aluno, int *matricula, char *nome, char *curso);

/* Atribui novos valores aos campos de um aluno */
void atribui(Aluno *aluno, int matricula, char *nome, char *curso);

/* Retorna o tamanho em bytes do TAD aluno */
int size();
```

#### Arquivo aluno.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct aluno{
    int matricula;
    char nome[50];
    char curso[20];
}Aluno;

Aluno *novo(int matricula, char *nome, char *curso){
    Aluno *a;
    a=malloc(sizeof(Aluno));
    a->matricula=matricula;
    strcpy(a->nome,nome);
    strcpy(a->curso,curso);

}

void libera(Aluno *aluno){
    free(aluno);
}

void acessa(Aluno *aluno, int *matricula, char *nome, char *curso){
    matricula=(int*)&aluno->matricula;
    nome=(char*)&aluno->nome;
    curso=(char*)&aluno->curso;
}

void atribui(Aluno *aluno, int matricula, char *nome, char *curso){
    aluno->matricula=matricula;
    strcpy(aluno->nome,nome);
    strcpy(aluno->curso,curso);
}

int size(){
    return (int)sizeof(Aluno);
}
```

#### Arquivo test.c

```
int main()
{
    Aluno *a;
    a=malloc(sizeof(size()));
    a=novo(123,"victhor","computacao");

    int *matricula;
    char *nome, *curso;

    acessa(a,matricula,nome,curso);

    printf("Matrícula: %d\n",*matricula);
    printf("Nome: %s\n", nome);
    printf("Curso: %s\n", curso);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O código tem vários problemas. Alguns são de organização e não resolvi todos eles. Eu não usaria essa função `acessa`, pelo menos dessa forma não está sendo útil, pode ser que depois ela seja mudada para ser mais útil. Com os *warnings* adequados ligados e eles deveriam estar ligados para ajudar achar os problemas, esse código nem compilaria.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct aluno {
    int matricula;
    char nome[50];
    char curso[20];
} Aluno;

Aluno *novo(int matricula, char *nome, char *curso) {
    Aluno *a = malloc(sizeof(Aluno)); // o ideal é receber o espaço já alocado
    a->matricula = matricula;
    strcpy(a->nome, nome);
    strcpy(a->curso, curso);
    return a; //não tinha return aqui
}

void libera(Aluno *aluno) {
    free(aluno);
}

void acessa(Aluno *aluno, int *matricula, char *nome, char *curso) {
    *matricula = aluno->matricula; //não estava jogando o dando em um ponteiro
    strcpy(nome, aluno->nome); //não estava copiando uma *string* para a outra
    strcpy(curso, aluno->curso);
}

void atribui(Aluno *aluno, int matricula, char *nome, char *curso) {
    aluno->matricula = matricula;
    strcpy(aluno->nome, nome);
    strcpy(aluno->curso, curso);
}

int size() {
    return (int)sizeof(Aluno);
}

int main() {
    Aluno *a = novo(123, "victhor", "computacao"); //simplifiquei e não aloquei de novo
    int matricula; //o dado não é um ponteiro
    char nome[50], curso[20]; //reserve o espaço para a *string*
    acessa(a, &matricula, nome, curso); //aqui manda o endereço da variável
    printf("Matrícula: %d\n", matricula);
    printf("Nome: %s\n", nome);
    printf("Curso: %s\n", curso);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Esuro8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/makfvtmx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Crud.c).

Comment: Vlw cara, resolveu tudo aki.